# Error encountered with version of Mediapipe in the project of recognizing numbers by fingers

Tags: python, mediapipe

I got the following error:

```
WARNING: All log messages before absl::InitializeLog() is called are written to STDERR
F0000 00:00:1699179362.286673 14712 collection.h:56] Failed to get tag "C55__PACKET" index 0
*** Check failure stack trace: ***
     @00007FFE46731DE9 (unknown)
     @00007FFE46048D38 (unknown)
     @00007FFE4609717D (unknown)
     @00007FFE46433F90 (unknown)
     @00007FFE4642EB60 (unknown)
     @00007FFE4642F63B (unknown)
     @00007FFE46455148 (unknown)
     @00007FFE46455558 (unknown)
     @00007FFE46454CAF (unknown)
     @00007FFEA8591542 (unknown)
     @00007FFEAACE6FD4 (unknown)
     @00007FFEAAE1CEC1 (unknown)
```

Can you help me fix the error?

I need the version of Mediapipe suitable for my project

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.